# Probability-Expectation of the maximum of 5 dice

Tags: probability, expectation

I am trying to understand part c of the following question (taken from Pitman's Probability, Chapter 3.1). I understand the solution using the difference of the max probabilities but I don't get the symmetry argument.

More specifically where is the 7 coming from? Intuitively it makes sense that the minimum and maximum would be symmetrical but I just can't figure out why it's this particular relation.

A hint would be much appreciated.

[image: Problem]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
7-1 & = 6 \\
7-2 & = 5 \\
7-3 & = 4 \\
7-4 & = 3 \\
7-5 & = 2 \\
7-6 & = 1 \\
\uparrow & \phantom{={}} \uparrow \\
a & \phantom{{}={}} b
\end{align}
In column $a$ you see the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$ and in column $b$ you see those same six numbers.

If the outcome $X$ is one of the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6,$ all with equal probabilities, then $7-X$ is also one of those six numbers, all with equal probabilities.

And if the **maximum** in five trials $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5$ is $M$, then the **minimum** of $7-X_1,7-X_2, 7-X_3,7-X_4, 7-X_5,7-X_6$  is $7-M.$

Answer (score 2):

The $7$ comes because of the symmetry of probabilities.  The probability of rolling $X$ is the same as the probability of rolling $7-X$.  If you want to compute the expectation of the minimum, you could follow through the calculation for the maximum but changing the direction of the $\le$ signs.  An alternate approach is to calculate the expectation of the maximum of $7-\text{ roll}$ for each die and subtract from $7$.  This only requires that $P(1)=P(6), P(2)=P(5), P(3)=P(4)$, but the three probabilities could be different and the calculation would still work.